# Compare a char[] and a char*

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, compare

I have a function that returns a `char*` (a name). I need to check if the name is the same as a name I type in when I run the program. 
So how can I compare a char pointer and a char array? (this is a part of a school assignment)

Comment: Have you at least tried to search for the answer on this site?

Answer (score 8):

In C++, you'd return `std::string` not `char*`, and compare with

```
if (returned == expected)
```

If you're trying to write a ghastly mixture of C and C++, then you could either make a string to compare:

```
if (std::string(pointer) == expected)
```

or use the C library

```
if (std::strcmp(pointer, expected) == 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use strcmp like

```
char a[] = "someName";
char* b = GetSomeOtherName();
if (strcmp(a, b) == 0)
{
    // equal
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strcmp()` from `<cstring>` header like

```
if ( strcmp ( func() , a ) == 0 )
{
   // they are equal
}
```

where `func()` returns the pointer and `a` is your character array.

But, while you are on C++ , you should use `std::string` . It is much better than character arrays.

It's really easy to check strings for equality. You could just do

```
std::string string1;
std::string string2;

//  assign them some values

if ( string1 == string2 )
{
   // they are equal
}
```